# how to merge a shop entity to a client entity (many to one) in jsf

Tags: jsf, jpa, ejb, facelets

I'm trying to merge an existing shop to a new client in jsf but it isn't successful. The program consists basically off a backing bean controller,an ejb and the jsf page (register) I have been able to  populate the shoplist in a comboBox UI. here is the code.

register.xhtml:

`clientcontroller.client.fname` is a SFSB.
`Property` already persisted but trying to be merged.
A shop from a list (`shopcontroller.shopList`)

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="3" >
<h:outputText value="Select From.  
 Available    Shops :" />     
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#. 
 {shopController.shop}" >
 <f:selectItems var="s" value="#.    
 {shopController.shopList}" />   
  </h:selectOneMenu>

 <h:commandButton value="register".   
  action="#{clientcontroller.Register(s)}" />
 </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

backing bean class:

```
ManagedBean(name="clientcontroller")
@RequestScoped
public class clientController {

@EJB ClientEJB clientEJB;

 private Client clt = new Client();
 private Shop shp = new Shop();
 private String clientfname;

//getters and setters

public String Register(Shop shp){
  this.shp = shp;
  clientEJB.register(clt, shp);
  return ""; 
}
```

EJB class:

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class ClientEJB {

  @PersistenceContext 
  EntityManager em;


  public void addClient(Client clt){
    em.persist(clt);
  }

  public void register(Client c ,Shop s){
    c.getShopList().add(s);
    s.setAvailability("false");
    s.setClientid(c);
    em.merge(s);
    em.merge(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? What are you expecting and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your code as follows:

XHTML:

```
  <h:commandButton value="register" action="#{clientcontroller.Register}" />
```

ManagedBean

```
  public String Register(){
      clientEJB.register(clt, shp);
      return ""; 
  }
```

See Also:

- [JSF 2 dropdown box example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-dropdown-box-example/)